# POST complex type with ignored property to OData Action with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have the following OData builder config. Which defines an Action `Create` with a few parameters. Note that I ignore the property `Password`. That's important later.

```
var userEntitySetName = nameof(UsersController).Replace("Controller", string.Empty);
var users = builder.EntitySet<User>(userEntitySetName);
users.EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Id);
users.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.Password);

var userCreateAction = users.EntityType.Collection.Action("Create").ReturnsFromEntitySet<User>(userEntitySetName);
userCreateAction.Parameter<int>("number");
```

I can then choose to do either

```
userCreateAction.EntityParameter<User>("user");
```

Or

```
userCreateAction.Parameter<User>("user");
```

The description for `Parameter` says: "Adds a new non-binding parameter". `EntityParameter` doesn't have a description. But I assume it's a binding parameter. Whatever that means. (Please explain)

More on these two choices later.

**My User class**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } // remember this is ignored
}
```

**My controller action**

```
[ODataRoute("Users/Create")]
public IHttpActionResult PostCreate(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    // omitted
}
```

**My request payload**

```
{
    "number": 1,
    "user":{ "FirstName": "foo", "LastName": "bar", "Password": "123" }
}
```

When I POST the above request `parameters` is `null`. However if I POST it without the ignored property `Password` then it works as expected.

This is where I assumed that using `EntityParameter` would use the `User` entity defined by the OData builder. The one without the `Password` property.
And `Parameter` would use the actual `User` type, including the `Password` property. Allowing me to do the above request.

But that's not the case :(

So I'm confused about the difference between `Parameter` and `EntityParameter`. Can someone explain their intended use?

**But hold on there's more.**
This is where I got really confused.

If I reduce the number of parameters to my action to only have the complex `User` type and change my controller action to:

```
[ODataRoute("Users/Create")]
public IHttpActionResult PostCreate(User user)
{
    // omitted
}
```

Then I can do a POST request with the `Password` property included. Note it's no longer wrapped in another object.

```
{ "FirstName": "foo", "LastName": "bar", "Password": "123" }
```

Which is nice. But I need the additional parameters :(

I guess the real question boils down to: "How can I POST ignored properties to my multi parameter action?"

Thanks

---

**Update**

I can't get the POST with `Password` to work anymore. I'm sure I had it working earlier. So please take the last part with a grain of salt.
The question is still valid though :)

Answer (score 1):

The first question: EntityParameter also is adding an non-binding entity type parameter. If you add a binding entity type, it means you bind this action to a entity or entityset, see function: SetBindingParameter.

So why you use `Parameter` function can get password property? This is because when you call `Parameter` we will search `User` type in complex types and primitive types in your model and we can't get it, so we build a complex type for your `User` type using the CLR type which have `password` property, and use `EntityParameter` function will get the `User` entity type in the model which doesn't have the `password` property.

Comment: That was what I was expecting. So why doesn't it work? When I POST a user entity with a password the ODataActionParameters object is null. Even though I used the non-binding parameter.

Comment: because  in the EdmModel the user doesn't have password property

Comment: I must have misunderstood what you said. So it's impossible to get the `ODataActionParameters` to correctly map `User` with the ignored `Password` property?

Comment: It's not right to ignore the password and want to get it, will this feature help you to remove password in the Get and remain it in the model http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-01-modelbound-attribute?

Comment: I read the link, but didn't find anything that seems related to my issue. Also I think you misunderstood my intent. I don't want to `GET` the password. I want to `POST` it. But I can't use the `User.Password` property because when I include password in the json payload the `ODataActionParameters` is `null` because it thinks that the `User` payload is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old post but. Why you didn't create just a request model class like

```
public class UserRequestModel 
{
   int number;
   User user;
}
```

after that define this Complex Type to your OData model.

after that call your controller method like you mentioned;

```
[ODataRoute("Users/Create")]
public IHttpActionResult PostCreate(UserRequestModel userRequestModel)
{
    // omitted
}
```

This is two cent in my pocket.

Good evening.